# Division of a three-place number into a five-place number, each digit have been replaced by a code letter, reconstruct and show solution is unique.

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I'm currently working in the following excercise:

> In the following division of a three-place number into a five-place number each digit have been replaced by a code letter. Assuming only that the remainder, Y, is not zero, reconstruct the problem and show that the solution is unique.

[image]

I've started, for the first operation with:

$$U \cdot LMN = RTYX$$

I've been trying to check if the potential numbers may be divisible by ten in order to find the first component but I've been unable to, and I'm not sure about it to be the correct way. Another way I tried to follow is to check the term $RSTUN$ divisibility by many numbers but I haven't reached any good result yet.

I would really appreciate any hint or help about how to proceed in this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: $T=5$ is not possible because $S$ is either $2T$ or $2T+1$ and the subtraction would borrow from the column $R$ is in.  A previous version of the question asserted that $T=5$

Comment: The first thing I notice is that $T$ is $4$ or less because two of them (maybe plus $1$) add up to $S$ without a carry.  Also two $Y$s (maybe plus $1$) add up to $T$ or $T+10$.  That gives the following $T,Y$ possibilities:  $(4,2),(4,7),(3,1),(3,6),(2,1),(2,6),(1,0),(1,5)$  Next I count ten different letters, so all the digits are used.  I enjoy puzzles like this, but this one doesn't seem to give much to work with.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you so much for sharing your valuable thoughts, I'll keep working with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{array}{r}
   &&&&&&&U&X\\
   &&&&-&-&-&-&- \\
   L&M&N&)&R&S&T&U&N \\
   &&&&R&T&Y&X \\
   &&&&-&-&-&- \\
   &&&&&T&Y&Y&N \\
   &&&&&T&Y&Y&J \\
   &&&&&-&-&-&- \\
   &&&&&&&&Y
\end{array}

Out of the ten letters, $\{L,M,N,R,S,T,U,X,Y\}$

- L, R, T, U can't be $0$ because they are the first digit of a number.
- X, Y can't be zero or because of  the column 
   $\quad \begin{array}{c}U\\X\\-\\Y\end{array}\quad$
- Similarly J (and Y) can't be $0$.
- N can't be $0$ because UN mod $10$ equals X and X $\ne 0$.
- S can't be $0$ because of 
   $\quad \begin{array}{cC}R&S\\ R&T\\ -&-\\ &T \end{array}$

Thus $M = 0$.

This means that

- $UN = 10Y + X$
- $XN = 10Y + J$
- $UL = 10R + T$
- $XL = 10T + Y$

As @RossMillikan said, $T \in \{1,2,3,4\}$. 
Note that, if $Y \ge 5$, then $S$ has to be odd.
And if $Y \le 4$, then $S$ has to ber even. That implies these possibilities.

\begin{array}{c}
T & S & Y \\
\hline
1 & 3 & 5 \\
2 & 4 & 1 \\
2 & 5 & 6 & *\\
3 & 6 & 1 & *\\
3 & 7 & 6 \\
4 & 8 & 2 \\
4 & 9 & 7 & *
\end{array}

Because $M=0$, then $XL = 10T+Y$ needs to be a product of two digits. So we can remove the starred items.

\begin{array}{c}
T & S & Y \\
\hline
1 & 3 & 5 \\
2 & 4 & 1 \\
3 & 7 & 6 \\
4 & 8 & 2
\end{array}